# What does ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code so far:

```
import statistics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1]) 
# replace this with wherever the  file is.

magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
average = statistics.mean(magnitudes)
sd = statistics.stdev(magnitudes)
below = sd*3

i = 0
while(i < len(df['Magnitude '])):
    if(abs(df['Magnitude '][i]) <=  (average - below)):
        tim = print(df['Time '][i])
        mag = df['Magnitude '][i]


    i += 1

window = 2
num = 1
x = tim
y = mag


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (units)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (units)')
plt.show()

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Currently, it outputs this:

```
/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/bin/python. 
"/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py"
2456116.494
2456116.535
2456116.576
2456116.624
2456116.673
2456116.714
2456116.799
2456123.527
2456166.634
2456570.526
2456595.515
2457485.722
2457497.93
2457500.674
2457566.874
2457567.877
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 40, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, y)
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2761, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1646, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 216, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 322, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError("x, y, and format string must not be None")
ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None
```

I am unsure of how to fix this code error. I believe it is due to `Tim` and `mag` being defined in that function. But I do not know how to solve it.
I would like for my code to be able to print a graph with a selected point and 10 points on either side. If anyone could help solve the error it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `tim = print(df['Time '][i])` sets `tim` to `None` (because `print` doesn't return anything). This is the cause of the error. Replace with `tim = df['Time '][i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
tim = print(df['Time '][i])
```

to:

```
print(df['Time '][i])
tim = df['Time '][i]
```